# Boost::log stops logging right after initialization

Tags: c++, logging, boost, scope

I have a small project that uses boost::log version 2 (from Boost 1.55). I want to log to a file, so I initialize it like this :

```
void initializeLogging(boost::log::trivial::severity_level level)
{        
    logging::add_common_attributes();                                                              

    logging::add_file_log(
        keywords::file_name = "sample.%02N.log", 
        keywords::open_mode = std::ios::app,
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] %Message%"
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= level
    );

    boost::log::sources::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level > lg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::error) << "INSIDE An error severity message";
}
```

I see the line `INSIDE An error severity message` in the file sample.00.log.

But when I call `doStuff`, right after, `initializeLogging` nothing is logged.

```
void doStuff()
{
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level > lg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::error) << "An error severity message";
}
```

This code is in a Windows program, there is no console at can look at. There is nothing in Windows Debug log either.

As you can see, `doStuff` has the exact same code as in the first function. Is there something I need to do to make my logging settings permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Is `boost::log::sources::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level >` a singleton?

You created another local variable `lg` for doStuff(), if it's not a singleton, it won't have the initialization.

The initialization:

```
logging::add_common_attributes();                                                              

logging::add_file_log(
    keywords::file_name = "sample.%02N.log", 
    keywords::open_mode = std::ios::app,
    keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] %Message%"
);

logging::core::get()->set_filter
(
    logging::trivial::severity >= level
);
```